# Cartthrob Subscriptions and PayPal Pro

Tags: expresso-store, cartthrob, paypal, brilliantretail

Looking at various add ons for Expressionengine I found Cartthrobs Subscription module which looks almost perfect for my requirement. When I say almost, the issue is that my customer is using PayPal pro but in the documentation for Subscriptions it says it only supports:

- Authorize.net (CIM)
- eWay (Token Payments)
- Payleap (SCM)
- Sage (Token)
- Stripe

Surely there will be a way to set up using PayPal pro for the gateway but I dont know if this will be possible? Is there an alternative if not?

I'm struggling to find out for definite if I can make it work with PayPal Pro.

Thanks
Guy

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you checkout Subscriptions from DevDemon instead. They have great support and their new module is really robust. I know it doesn't support PayPal Pro at the moment but maybe you can look into extending it through their plugin architecture or possibly paying them to add it.

http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/subscriptions

Comment: It still does not Support PayPal. Stripe and Authorize.net are the only options.